# what is the best approach when there are 2 partial correct answers?

Tags: discussion

With this [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/20598/post-slavery-segregation-outside-of-the-us) there are 2 responses which answer the question. both are valid and give good different examples of the situation.
any advice on how to accept essentially 2 or more answers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as one of the answerers . . . don't sweat it. You can accept whichever turned out to be most useful to you, whichever you enjoyed reading more, or whichever had most community support. If you honestly find them equivalent on all metrics, then you could consider not accepting an answer. That way community support is the only determinant of their ordering.

Comment: Slight bit of disagreement here. I'd prefer to see an acceptance eventually, if you can bring yourself to give one. To me no acceptance means no answer was helpful, and/or you would like more answers. OTOH, on my questions I have an abysmally low acceptance rate: 40% here, and about 84% on StackOverflow, so I guess I'm not practicing what I'm preaching.

Comment: When I read through the archives, I often wish a question had no accepted answer. It's already hard enough for 3rd or 4th questions to get any attention, even without having an answer pinned to the top. There are a lot of great answers on the site languishing with one upvote underneath an okay accepted answer with 10. I guess that's beside the point though, and the little green check is meant to indicate "Stack Exchange worked for me." Community support seems like a reasonable criteria to us as tiebreaker here--and everyone seem to much prefer apartheid to castas.

Comment: Lol. As long as we are arguing against accepting our own answers, I'd like to point out that if an answer gets to +10 over the accepted answer, the poster gets a badge. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 1):

Consider offering and awarding multiple bounties.